# Flex Keyboard.capslock returns always false in creationComplete

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, keyboard, capslock

Im trying to notify user in login screen if CapsLock is on. In creationComplete Keyboard.capslock returns always false. Is there any workaround for this? Here is what i try:

```
protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    callLater(setListener);
}

private function setListener():void
{   
    if (Keyboard.capsLock)
    {
        lblCapsLock.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblCapsLock.visible = false;
    }

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, application1_keyDownHandler);
}

protected function application1_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.CAPS_LOCK)
    {
        if (Keyboard.capsLock)
        {
            lblCapsLock.visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lblCapsLock.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a bug reported in Adobe Bug and Issue Management System: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-2033

I wonder why it's in state Cannot Reproduce

Comment: I've tested, it seems to be OK. Rather strange... BTW, just an advice to optimeze your code: lblCapsLock.visible = Keyboard.capsLock.

Comment: For me it does not work. If I click stage before creation complete is dispatched, label will be shown if caps is on. Some how I need to set focus to Application, then Keyboard.capsLock is true.

Comment: @J.Lantinen, I think the application does need OS focus to be able to get access to the keyboard.  Is that really a problem? Couldn't you instead add an event listener for focusIn instead of creationComplete? Or both?

Comment: Added focusIn listener, then it works better. Thank you for the tip J_A_X.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but this may help someone... found with the wmode set to transparent the keyboard.capsLock value is always false. Or it may only be swfobject specific.